# Beta "site stats" displaying extra space between numbers

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

There is extra space between each number in the *Site Stats* section on the right of all StackExchange beta sites (with the "blueprint" theme):

[image: site stats scrolling]

It appears on Mozilla Firefox 3.6 and Google Chrome 10 on Linux as well as Google Chrome 10 and Internet Explorer 8 on Windows, and the same thing happens on at least Skeptics and Science Fiction & Fantasy

<strike>**Edit:**  I performed a hard refresh on both SciFi and Skeptics and I'm still seeing the extra space.</strike>
Fixed now, thanks!

Comment: @Patches you'll want to remove the [status-completed] tag then, and I am confirming that I see it on every Beta site I've tried as well (latest Chrome on Windows)

Comment: @Daniel:  The software won't permit me to remove that tag.  It says `the moderator tag 'status-completed' must be present`.

Comment: @Patches: Next time, just roll back.

Comment: @bor FYI we mark things completed *when they are checked into source control*. Deployments generally happen every 24 hours.

Comment: @JefAtwood: I know. I was talking about the next time he thinks the tag doesn't fit.

Comment: @Jeff it's a bit hard to confirm then, isn't it?  I mean I know you guys do your own confirmation and all, but I wonder if there's a better approach (waiting until deployment to remove the tag stinks too, I understand)

Comment: @Borror0: Thank you for clarifying that.  I thought you meant I was supposed to have rolled back my edit when I discovered it worked now.

Comment: @Jeff: Wouldn't status-planned be a better choice in those circumstances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.